# Better coding for a jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, performance

I'm starting a plugin, it is going to be a "big" plugin, with a lot of code...

What you guys sugest me to do ?

Approach 1

```
    $.Config = { myValue : 'My Value 1' }
    $.Test_1 = function(){ }
    $.Test_1.myFunction = function()
    {
        alert('My Function 1');
    }
    $.Test_1.access = function()
    {
        alert( $.Config.myValue );
    }
    $.Test_1.access();
```

Approach 2 ( I prefer )

```
    $.Test_2 = {
        Config : {
            myValue : 'My Value 2'
        } ,

        myFunction : function()
        {
            alert('My Function 2');
        } ,

        access : function()
        {
            alert( this.Config.myValue );
        }
    }
    $.Test_2.access();
```

I prefer the second approach, it is more cleaner and better to understand, but i don't know if it is more effient or not..

The plugin is to a chat application like Zopim and similars, it will work with Pusher.com and it will be available in various languages, etc... i want it to be easy to setup that's why i have the $.Config and Config variables there...

Please let me know what you guys think about this, thanks !

Comment: Neither option is the [canonical way to write a jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: I voted to close this. You should read http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring in its entirety.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would be asking these questions to myself:

- Will my plugin be instantiable? If someone uses my plugin, could he be using it more than once in one page?
- Will my plugin use an element to initiate like $(element).myplugin(), or will it just be called like $.myplugin(), or both?
- How will my plugin handle events on the static DOM and the DOM it creates?
- Can some one late-bind a function to my plugin's events? like:

  `$(element).bind("onmypluginevent",function()...`

The approach you want to use may vary according to the questions above. Find the most suitable approach to your goal before you start coding.

You may want to search **jquery plugin boilerplate** to find examples how people do it.

Comment: Thanks, and for the third point the plugin will not use any element to initiate, but i will take a look at the jquery plugin boilerplate you mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

approach 2 is much more readable, nested, cleaner, and [according to tests](http://jsperf.com/aaasd) - 92% faster.
but you should read the [jQuery documentations](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) about how to do it the right way.